# Create a docker container on demand in a cluster

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker swarm cluster.
I have a pre-configured docker image in my docker hub and i would like to run a container of the image on demand.
I have written an api which can go to a host and run a container.
But now, i want to spin up that container on **cluster** in stead of pointing to a single host.
I have seen docker-compose and docker-stack.
But as per the documentation 

`If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted volumes).`

So, how can i start a container on demand on a cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

In Swarm, you must create a service based on an image in order to create container. There is 2 mode, global to launch 1 container of this service on each machine, and replicated, load balancer of swarm will choose the machine which will host the container (of course you can add constraint with option --constraint).

```
docker service create --name=my_name --replicas=4 my_image
```

If you want to launch a container on demand, you must scale this service to the desire number of task (container).

```
docker service scale my_service=5
```

For instance you could use a SDK to get number of task of the service and scale it to number of task of service + 1.

In my own experience, Swarm is only good for stateless component (don't really know how to deal with database ...)

I hope i did not miss understand the question.

Comment: can i bring down a container on demand also using this docker service scale strategy ?

Comment: Of course, with docker scale you choose the number of replicas of a container (which is define by the image of the service). It mean you can put 0 as parameter of option to shutdown every container or do whatever you want.

You can use `docker service ls` on a manager node in order to see the number of container which are running by service. If you reach memory limit, you'll may see that every container of a service aren't launch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Docker container scaling is limited to replica setting with docker swarm. I think it is possible to launch container using Docker Engine API, however you can't do the same with Docker Swarm since launching is based on replica
https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/examples/